# IntelliJ Kotlin multiplatform project Gradle sync very long

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've created a new `Kotlin Multiplatform` project for `Andrid` and `iOS` (Mobile shared Library). The project works fine but every time I run `Gradle` sync, it takes **more than 5 minutes every time.** It always get stuck on the same line:

> Gradle: Build model 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinMPPGradleModel' for root project 'MyProject'

Why is it taking so long evey time?

I'm using `Gradle` version 5.1.
Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.8.1"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.11'
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions.incremental = false
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
        // This preset is for iPhone emulator
        // Switch here to presets.iosArm64 to build library for iPhone device
        fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common'
            }
        }
        androidMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
            }
        }
        androidTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
            }
        }
        iosMain {
        }
        iosTest {
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a known issue where Kotlin/Native dependencies are re-fetched every sync, which may be what you're seeing. You can see details and follow it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28128).

As posted to that issue, there's a workaround you may be able to try which essentially involves adding `{ content { excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native" } }` to every item in your `repositories` block.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest (Kotlin `1.3.21` and Gradle `5.2.1`) fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brucelet pointed out this is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28128). To supplement his answer, here is a full implementation of the workaround in `Groovy`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral().content() {
        excludeGroup "Kotlin/Native"
    }
    google().content() {
        excludeGroup "Kotlin/Native"
    }
    jcenter() {
        content {
            excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
        }
    }
    maven { 
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
        content {
            excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
        }
    }
}
```

and in `Kotlin DSL`:

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal().apply {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/soywiz/soywiz")
            content {
                includeGroup("com.soywiz")
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        jcenter() {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        google().apply {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the Gradle task from command lines with --parallel option.

Otherwise, fllow this guide to profile Gradle execution https://guides.gradle.org/performance/

Comment: I already tried everything in this guide. The problem is not with the build which is quick, it's only with the sync.